# .Net framework requires for SQLite installation

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm trying to install ADO.NET 2.0 provider for SQLite. when start of the installation it says

[image]

and I pressed yes and I got .NET Framework from this page(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa496123)

But when I'm installing .NET Framework It gives a Warning like this

[image]

What could I do for solve this problem and install SQLite ADO.NET on my pc.

Comment: Install .NET 3.5 from Control Panel > Programs and Features.

Comment: it works .thank you .could you please explain why this gives an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

As @Dai mentioned in his comment we can install .Net framework 2.0 or 3.5 as an update via 'Windows Features' in the (Control Panel > Programs & features > turn windows features on or off).
[image]

complete Guide can be found at [groovypost.com](https://www.groovypost.com)

---

### Reason

This problem is because from Windows 8 and above, the .NET Framework is an OS component and cannot be independently uninstalled. Updates to the .NET Framework appear in the Installed Updates tab of the Control Panel Programs and Features app. For operating systems on which the .NET Framework is not preinstalled, the .NET Framework appears in the Uninstall or change a program tab (or the Add/Remove programs tab) of the Program and Features app in Control Panel.
source : [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925569(v=vs.110).aspx)